# Why console window is opening at a side on my exported Electron package

Tags: angular, electron

Browser console window is getting opening as seen below:

[image]

How can I get rid of this window, I don't want it to be opened.

Comment: In your app files, look for the file where you define your electron app configurations. Find the line calling `openDevTools()` method and comment or delete that line.

Comment: i am using this boilerplate code - `https://github.com/c4wrd/angular2-electron-boilerplate` and i am unable to find this code, can you advise -

Comment: See my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app files, look for the file where you define your electron app configurations. Find the line calling `openDevTools()` method and comment or delete that line.

As per your comment about the app template, open this file,

> https://github.com/c4wrd/angular2-electron-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.ts

... and remove or comment the line:

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
```

Answer (score 2):

Look through the code of your app, somewhere you're probably calling **openDevTools()**. If you remove this, the dev tools will not open automatically after startup.